# How to install pip wheel packages for a different platform

Tags: pip

Some deployment environments like AWS Lambda require creating a zip file containing the application code as well as all requirements in it. Usually installing the requirements into the build directory is straightforward:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt -t some_build_dir
```

This proves problematic when you're not running the same platform as the target on which the code will run, e.g. trying to deploy to a Linux environment while working from OS X.

There is the `--platform` option, but it also forces you to set the `--only-binary :all:` option, which then fails to install all packages without a wheel distribution.

How do I install the requirements into a target directory with wheel packages targeting a different platform while not impeding the installation of non-wheel packages?

Comment: `pip` cannot **install** alien packages, it can only **download** them. Perhaps you should download and pack such packages and install them after uploading the pack to AWS.

Answer (score 2):

Create separate requirements files for platform dependent wheels.

Then:

```
pip install -r requirements_sdist_and_universal_wheels.txt -t some_build_dir
pip install -r requirements_platform_dependent_wheels.txt --plaform LukasOS --only-binary=:all: -t some_build_dir
```

Comment: This is a good-enough trivial solution if there isn't another way, but there must be a better way to do this. Surely I can't be the first to have this problem?